# How to rotate 3d usdz model in tapped direction with realityKit?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, realitykit

I am able to get the world transform from raycasting using the tapped 2d point, now suppose the 3d usdz model is facing completely opposite direction and is placed on an image using image tracking, I have to dynamically rotate that model so that its face points towards the direction in which user has tapped.

Note:- The angle should be calculated dynamically based on the rayCasting result.

Answer (score 0):

Set the rotation of the model so that it would rotate .pi radians about the y axis (yaw).

```
let rotationTransform = Transform.init(pitch: 0, yaw: .pi, roll: 0)
let newTransform = simd_mul(modelInitialTransform, rotationTransform.matrix)
model.move(to: newTransform, relativeTo: nil, duration: 0.3, timingFunction: .easeInOut)
```

Comment: Thank you but the angle rotation should be dynamic, based on the point tapped by the user.

Comment: Get the world transform of the point the user has tapped and use the look(at:) function of Transform to orient the object toward the tapped point.

Comment: Sorry but it is not exactly clear can you give me a sample code